# how i can do many submit in one page with php?

Tags: php, mysql

I am devlopping an application with php and i would adding 2 buttons in one page php and i'm passing the name of each bottons to the function (POST) like this (isset($_POST['action'])) but i can't do it can you help me

```html
<?php 
$host = "localhost"; 
 $user = "root"; 
 $db = "reseau"; 
 $con = @mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
 $select = @mysql_select_db ('reseau') ;  

if (isset($_POST['action'])) {
    if(isset($_POST['nom'])) $nom = htmlspecialchars(pg_escape_string($_POST['nom']));
 else      $nom="";
 if(isset($_POST['prenom'])) $prenom =  htmlspecialchars(pg_escape_string($_POST['prenom']));
 else      $prenom="";
 if(isset($_POST['email'])) $email = $email =  htmlspecialchars(pg_escape_string($_POST['email']));
 else      $email="";
 if(isset($_POST['password'])) $password =  htmlspecialchars(pg_escape_string($_POST['password']));
 else      $password="";
 if(isset($_POST['naissance'])) $naissance =  htmlspecialchars(pg_escape_string($_POST['naissance']));
 else      $naissance="";
 if(isset($_POST['sexe'])) $sexe =  htmlspecialchars(pg_escape_string($_POST['sexe']));
 else      $sexe="";
 $query = "INSERT INTO usager(nom,prenom,email,password,naissance,sexe) VALUES ('" . $nom . "', '" . $prenom . "', '" . $email . "', '" . $password . "', '" . $naissance . "', '" . $sexe . "')";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if (!$result) {
    $errormessage = mysql_error();
    echo "Error with query: " . $errormessage;
    exit();
    }
}
else if(isset($_POST['enter'])){
  if(empty($_POST['nom']) === false && empty($_POST['password']) === false){
   $nom = htmlspecialchars(pg_escape_string(trim($_POST['nom'])));
   $password = htmlspecialchars(pg_escape_string(trim($_POST['password'])));
   $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usager WHERE nom = '$nom' AND password = '$password'")or die(mysql_error());
   $count = mysql_num_rows($query);
   if($count == 0){
    $output= "combinaison nom d'utilisateur/mot de passe incorrecte. réessayez";
   }else{
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['nom']=htmlspecialchars(pg_escape_string(trim($_POST['nom'])));
    $_SESSION['password']=htmlspecialchars(pg_escape_string(trim($_POST['password'])));
    header("Location: index1.php");
   }
  }else{
   $output= 'veuillez saisir tout les champs';
  }
 }

?>
<!DOCemail html>
<html>
<body style="background-image:url(6a00e554acca9b8834014e86765de6970d.jpg);
background-attachment : fixed;
background-position   : 50% 50%;
background-size       : cover;
">
 <form name="nl" action="" method="POST">
  <fieldset style="width: 370px; margin-top: 100px;">
  <legend style= "left: 120px;">Creer un compte</legend>
  <p><label for="text">Nom</label><input required placeholder="votre nom" title="Ce texte ne doit comprendre que des lettres"  id="text" email="text" name="nom" style="height: 31px; margin-left: 25px;"/></p>
  <p><label for="email">Prenom</label><input required placeholder="votre prenom " id="email" type="text" name="prenom"style="height: 31px; margin-left: 25px;" /></p>
  <p><label for="password">Email</label><input required placeholder="votre email " id="url" type="text" name="email" style="height: 31px; margin-left: 25px;"/></p>
  <p><label for="url">Mot de passe</label><input required placeholder="votre mot de passe " id="url"type="password" name="password" style="height: 31px; margin-left: 25px;"/></p>
        <p><label for="url" style="width: 147px;">Date de naissance</label><input required id="birthdate" name="naissance" type="date" style="height: 31px;"/></p>
  <p><label style="
    width: 90px;
">Sexe</label><a>homme</a>
    <input type="radio" name="sexe" value="male"
 checked="checked" style="
    width: 20px;
"/>
  <a>femme</a>
    <input type="radio" value="women" name="sexe" style="
    width: 20px;
"/></p>
  </fieldset>
   <button type='submit' name='action' class="button" value="action" style="
  padding-left: 18px;
  padding-right: 18px;
  padding-top: 13px;
  padding-bottom: 13px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  border-top-width: 0px;
  margin-right: 950px;
  ">Inscription</button>
  <div id="main" class="container" style="left: 1150px;top: 270px;"> 
 <fieldset>
 <legend style="
    margin-left: 65px;
">Login In</legend>
 <p class="login-username"> 
  <label for="nom">Nom:</label> <input type="text" name="nom" id="user_login" class="input" value="" size="20"
  placeholder="Username" style="
    height: 36px;
"> 
 </p>
 <p class="login-password"> 
  <label for="password">Mot de passe</label> <input type="password" name="password" id="user_pass" class="input" value="" size="20" placeholder="Password" style="
    height: 36px;
"> 
 </p> 
 <p class="login-remember">
  <label><input name="rememberme" type="checkbox" id="rememberme" value="forever"> Remember Me</label>
 </p> 
 <p class="login-submit"> 
  <input type='submit' name='enter' id="wp-submit" class="button-primary" value="Sign In" style="
    width: 110px;
    height: 36px;
"/>
 </p>
</fieldset> 
 </div>
  </form>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Create 2 different forms.

Comment: Create two different forms with different name for submit button.

Comment: print $_POST ans check what you are getting on submit

Comment: i don't understand how do you mean can you modified in the code?

Comment: you can have any number of submit buttons, don't break the form in to 2.
Just check on click of `action` button what value is posted??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two submit button. Give a same name to two submit input with different value.

```
<input type="submit" name="btn_name" value="First Button"/>
<input type="submit" name="btn_name" value="Second Button"/>
```

And check it like,

```
if(isset($_POST) && isset($_POST['btn_name']))
{
  if($_POST['btn_name'] == "First Button")
   {
      // first button clicked
   }
  else if($_POST['btn_name'] == "Second Button")
{
  // second button clicked
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add **name tag** in both button and check using **isset()** function

```
<input type="submit" name="btn1" value="btn1" />
<input type="submit" name="btn2" value="btn2" />


if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    //something posted

    if (isset($_POST['btn1'])) {
        // btn1
    } else {
        //btn2
    }
}
```